# Sending message to android emulator using firebase cloud message

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-push-notification

I am testing to send a notification to my android emulator, it is working as it prints the details as it able to receive and means that is being triggered but the problem here is it doesn't pop up and even show on the notification panel of the android.

**Firebase cloud messaging**
[image]

**Terminal**
[image]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.rnfirebaseapp101">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />                                               
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground" android:value="false"/>
      <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
      <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color" android:resource="@color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->
      <!-- <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
      android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" /> -->
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
      <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
          <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

      <service
        android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
      </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT:

Here is the guide I am following: https://blog.jscrambler.com/implementing-react-native-push-notifications-in-android-apps